# Test Class works fine in Dev org, but when packaging it failed?

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller

Here is the code for my controller and my test class. It worked fine in the dev org but when I tried to package it up it failed with the following error:

> System.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to de-reference a null object on the Stack Trace
>   Class.SalesHistoryControllerTest.testMyController: line 7, column 1.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

**Controller**

```
public class SafeSalesHistoryOverviewController {
    public Id AccountId { get; set; }
    public String SelectedYear { get; set; }
    public String Year2 { get; set; }
    public String Year3 { get; set; }
    public String Year4 { get; set; }
    public String Year5 { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> Options { get; set; }
    public SafeSalesHistoryOverviewController() {
        SelectedYear = String.valueOf(System.Today().year());
        Year2 = String.valueOf(System.today().year()-1);
        Year3 = String.valueOf(System.today().year()-2);
        Year4 = String.valueOf(System.today().year()-3);
        Year5 = String.valueOf(System.today().year()-4);

        Options = new List<SelectOption>();

        Options.add(new SelectOption(SelectedYear, SelectedYear));
        Options.add(new SelectOption(Year2, Year2));
        Options.add(new SelectOption(Year3, Year3));
        Options.add(new SelectOption(Year4, Year4));
        Options.add(new SelectOption(Year5, Year5))
    }
    public List<Sales_History__c> Sales_Histories {
        get{
            return [SELECT Id, Name, Account_Name__c, Invoice_Number__c, Sale_Date__c, Grand_Total__c, Account_Name_Text__c, Serial_Number__c FROM Sales_History__c WHERE Account_Name__c = :AccountId AND CALENDAR_YEAR(Sale_Date__c) = :Integer.valueOf(SelectedYear)];
        }
    }
    public PageReference Rerender() {
        return null; 
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class SalesHistoryControllerTest {

    public static testMethod void testMyController() {

        SafeSalesHistoryOverviewController controller = new SafeSalesHistoryOverviewController();
        String nextPage = controller.rerender().getUrl();

        controller = new SafeSalesHistoryOverviewController();

        nextPage = controller.Rerender().getUrl();

        System.assertEquals('apex/success', nextPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to pump some data into the object `Sales_History__c`?

Comment: I don't understand how it could work on your dev org. Your `Rerender` method in the controller returns `null`. But in your test, you're trying to call the `getUrl` method on this null value. So it's returning an error as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String nextPage = controller.rerender().getUrl();` In this line, it is returning null from this method:

```
public PageReference Rerender() {
  return null; 
}
```

That's the reason behind **NullPointerException**.

Comment: So what should I be updating in order to get this issue resolved?

Comment: what you are trying to test is not clear. If you try to test navigation then how are you navigating to next page? where is that coding?

Comment: I figured it out. I just removed the reference to the rerender. I still had enough code coverage to make the test successful. Thanks for your help.